# Renew Push Notification Token in React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, token

I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) in my cross-platform App (iOS and Android).

I have not clear at all how this plugin works, especially when a new PN Token is registered. At the moment, the App starts and the `PushNotification.configure({...})` function runs. So, when App registers to the Push Notification services (APN and GCM), it catches the event `onRegister:` and I am able to see the PN Token and save it on AsyncStorage, until now all is okay.

Problems come when for some reason the App must unregister this Token (we have to clean completely the AsyncStorage, and so we will lost the Token) but without uninstall the App itself from the device. We tried to run `PushNotification.abandonPermissions()` both before and after cleaning AsyncStorage, but it seems that when App is relaunched, the `onRegister:` event is catched anymore. So, our question is: when we have to delete the first generated PN Token, how to renew the PN Token without uninstall and reinstall the App?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) then you can try

```
 PushNotification.unregister();
```